# Protractor import csv code does'nt actually import, still jasmine shows spec is passed

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am assuming that variable fileToUpload should be an upload a file, but it is not working as I expected. Here is my sample:

```
deviceDetailReport() {
    var path = require('path');
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);
    var fileToUpload = '/home/rahul/Device_Template.csv',
    absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-message= "Import Device/s" ]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
    //element(by.className('[class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--colored md-btn btn-new btn btn--primary"]')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);      
}
```

File which i want to upload is present in location '/home/rahul/Device_Template.csv' and file name was 'Device_Template.csv', file having data

```
name    ||  address  ||  port ||    description  || authgroup  ||   admin-state ||  device-type ||  ned-id ||   protocol

AA-INFAA || 127.0.0.1 ||    8000 || Automation device ||    Test33 ||   unlocked || netconf ||      ssh
```

it is clearly show that file having name column and name starts with AA-INFAA, so if i upload this file this name appears on top but it is not showing and console shows this spec as passed

Comment: Please clarify `[ng-reflect-message= "Import Device/s" ]` is a file upload control or a text box to display the content of your csv file. If it's a file upload control, however you did not click button like 'submit' to trigger file uploading. If it's a textbox, you should read the content of csv file firstly, then send the file content to the textbox by sendKeys

Comment: its a file upload control and it is not required to click on trigger button because i am passing "absolutePath" in sendKeys() and 'absolutePath' having the file location so click option is not required it will upload a file directly

Comment: Sounds the file will be uploaded automatically once file choosen.  And seems the sendkeys can't trigger the auto uploading.  I guess only the change on the ng-model binded to the upload control can trigger the auto uploading.  The sendkey not fire the ng-model change.  Can you give HTML code of the upload control?